# Assigning Label based on quantile for every sub group

Tags: r, plyr

My data.frame looks like this:

```
Region  Store Sales
A        1    ***
A        2    ***
B        1    ***
B        2    ****
```

I want to create labels of store based on Sales Performance. That is if a store Sales is higher than 75% quantile assign "High" else low.
Applying ddply using the code

```
R3 <- ddply(dat, .(REGION), function(x) quantile(x$Sales, na.rm = TRUE))
```

returns a dataframe with all quantile numbers for the regions.
I can use that frame to join with original and do a if-else for each cluster. I am sure it's not an efficient way. Is there a better approach to it?

Comment: TRy `library(data.table);setDT(data)[, quantile(Sales, na.rm = TRUE), REGION]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
df %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
    mutate(Performance = ifelse(Sales > quantile(Sales, 0.75), 'High', 'Low'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Region [2]
#>   Region Store Sales Performance
#>    <chr> <int> <int>       <chr>
#> 1      A     1   100        High
#> 2      A     2    10         Low
#> 3      B     1    90        High
#> 4      B     2    10         Low
```

---

Data Input

```
df = read.table(text = 'Region  Store Sales
 A        1    100
               A        2    10
               B        1    90
               B        2    10', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: If i want to to add more condition, do i have to assign a custom function with if-then-else ?

Comment: @mezz yes you can , just using you self def function replace quantile

Comment: rn<-function(x) {
  if (x>quantile(x,.75,na.rm = TRUE)) {
    x='high'
  } else if (x<quantile(x,.25,na.rm = TRUE)) {
    x="low"
  } else
    x="Medium"
  
} dat%>%group_by(REGION)%>%mutate(Performance=rn(Sales)) doesn't seem to work

Comment: Check If this is what you need, `df%>%group_by(Region)%>%mutate(Performance=ifelse(Sales>quantile(Sales,0.75),'High',ifelse(Sales<quantile(Sales,0.25),'Low','Median')))`