# Category assigning based on percentile

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
Group Country GDP

    A     a       ***
    A     b       ***
    B     a       ***
    B     b       ***
```

I want to assign catagory to gdp (High,low) based on within group percentile rank by creating a new column.
This is what I tried

```
    def c(gr):
        ser=gr['gdp']
        p=np.nanpercentile(ser,50)
        for i in ser:
            if i>p:
                return "high"
            else:
                return "low"

grouped = df.groupby('Group')
df['perf']=grouped.apply(c)
```

Perf column is returning nan. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at `pd.cut` ?

Comment: Hi , I give the solution , it is similar with R :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and custom function:

```
def c(gr):
    ser=gr['gdp']
    #q=0.5 is by default, so can be omit 
    p = ser.quantile()
    gr['perf'] = np.where( ser > p, 'high', 'low')
    return gr

df = df.groupby('Group').apply(c)
```

This can be simplified by [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
q = df.groupby('Group')['gdp'].transform('quantile')
df['perf1'] = np.where(df['gdp'] > q, 'high', 'low')
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(12)

N = 15
L = list('abcd') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'gdp': np.random.rand(N)})
df = df.sort_values('Group').reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[[0,4,5,10,13,14], 'gdp'] = np.nan
#print (df)
```

---

```
def c(gr):
    ser=gr['gdp']
    #q=0.5 is by default, so can be omit 
    p = ser.quantile()
    gr['perf'] = np.where( ser > p, 'high', 'low')
    return gr

df = df.groupby('Group').apply(c)

q = df.groupby('Group')['gdp'].transform('quantile')
df['perf1'] = np.where( df['gdp'] > q, 'high', 'low')
print (df)
   Group       gdp  perf perf1
0      a       NaN   low   low
1      a  0.907267  high  high
2      a  0.456051   low   low
3      b  0.675998   low   low
4      b       NaN   low   low
5      b       NaN   low   low
6      b  0.563141   low   low
7      b  0.801265  high  high
8      c  0.372834   low   low
9      c  0.481530  high  high
10     c       NaN   low   low
11     d  0.082524   low   low
12     d  0.725954  high  high
13     d       NaN   low   low
14     d       NaN   low   low
```

Comment: To add more conditions I akm doing this :                                               def tr(group):
    ser=group['gdp'].dropna()
    for i in ser:
        if i>(ser.quantile(q=.75)):
            group['perf']="h"
        elif i<(ser.quantile(q=.25)):
            group['perf']="l"
        else:
            group['perf']="m"
    return group  (this is returning all gdp as "h")

Comment: Sorry, I totally forget. The best is use `q1 = df.groupby('Group')['gdp'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=.75))` `q2 = df.groupby('Group')['gdp'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=.25))` and then `df['perf1'] = np.where(df['gdp'] > q1, 'h', np.where(df['gdp'] < q2, 'l', 'm'))`. I am on phone only, so untested.

Answer (score 1):

Similar with [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016702/assigning-label-based-on-quantile-for-every-sub-group/46016777#46016777)

```
df['output']=df.groupby('Group').gdp.apply(lambda x : np.where(x>x.quantile(0.75),'High','Low')).apply(pd.Series).stack().dropna().values

df
Out[333]: 
   Group       gdp output
0      a       NaN    Low
1      a  0.772128    Low
2      a  0.070406    Low
3      a  0.859301   High
4      a       NaN    Low
5      a       NaN    Low
6      b  0.681299   High
7      b  0.040839    Low
8      c  0.896475   High
9      c  0.726527    Low
10     c       NaN    Low
11     c  0.244783    Low
12     c  0.563001    Low
13     c       NaN    Low
14     d       NaN    Low
```